# How to add new table row with all elements of previous row

Tags: javascript, html

I am in trouble here. I have a table inside a form with some input elements in one row, Now I want to generate a new row on click a button with all the same elements as in the previous row. What I did I can get the elements but not the style and class attributes.

```js
function addRow_P(tableID_P) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID_P);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        element1.class="i-checks"
        element1.style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
    
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var array = ["Alaska","New York",];
        var element3 = document.createElement("select");
        //element3.type = "text";
        element3.name = "type[]";
        //element3.placeholder = "Item name or model";
        element3.id = "inputSuccess";
        element3.class = "span12 form-control"
        // elememt3.width = "220px"
        cell2.appendChild(element3);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = array[i];
          option.text = array[i];
          element3.appendChild(option);
        }
    
    
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "name[]";
        element2.placeholder = "Item name or model";
        element2.id = "inputSuccess";
        element2.class = "span12 form-control"
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
      }
```

```html
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
                  <table class="table" id="product" style="margin-top: 10px" id="new-row" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                          <td>
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:30px">
                            <input  class="i-checks"  style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" type="checkbox">
                          </div>
                        </td>
                          <td width="600px">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="name">Product name</label>
                              <select class="select-product form-control"  style="width: 100%">
                                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                              </select>
                              <p class="help-block with-errors"></p>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td width="200px">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="name">Quantity</label>
                              <input  class="form-control" type="text"  name="quantity" pattern="^[0-9].{1,}$" maxlength="10" data-error="Numbers only" required>
                              <p class="help-block with-errors"></p>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td text-align="center">
                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:100px">
                              <label>New</label><br>
                              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle form-control" onclick="addRow_P('product')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add</button>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                         <!-- <td width="25%"> <input type="text" id="inputSuccess" name="serviceCharge[]"  placeholder="Enter service charge"> </td>-->
                      </tr>
                  </table>
    
    
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs" type="submit"><strong>Submit</strong></button>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Here is a screenshot what I want achieve
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`cloneNode( true )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

> The `Node.cloneNode()` method returns a duplicate of the node on which this method was called.
>
> **`deep`** Optional
>   true if the children of the node should also be cloned, or false to clone only the specified node.

```js
document.querySelector( "button" ).addEventListener( "click", () => {
  document.querySelector( "tbody" ).appendChild(
    document.querySelector( "tr" ).cloneNode( true )
  );
}, false );
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="foo" type="number">
        <input class="bar" type="text">
        <input style="display:block;" type="range">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="foo" type="number">
        <input class="bar" type="text">
        <input style="display:block;" type="range">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Clone row</button>
```

This method will clone the state of the HTML, but not the state of the values of any of the `<input>`s if changed from their defaults.
If this functionality (or any other) is also required, please comment below for a more detailed demo.

### Updated to include jQuery and other functionality per discussion

In the below example, the cloned row is targeted by `id`, so the clone has its `id` removed with [`removeAttr( 'id' )`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) so the `id` is not repeated through the HTML.

```js
$( 'button' ).click( function() {
  $( '#row_to_clone' ).clone().removeAttr( 'id' ).appendTo( 'tbody' );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row_to_clone">
      <td>
        <input class="foo" type="number">
        <input class="bar" type="text">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="baz" type="date">
        <input class="qux" type="email">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Clone row</button>
```

Comment: `$('#add-row').click(function(){
    $('#product tbody').appendChild(
      $('tr').cloneNode( true )
    );
  });`

this is what i did but geting error cloneNode is not a function

Comment: In jQuery, you may find [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) works. I am however unfamiliar with jQuery.

Comment: `$('#add-row').click(function(){
    $('#product tbody tr').clone().appendTo('tbody');
  });`

This did the work but its appending whatever I generated by last click but I want a row at a time

Comment: Will each row have its own "clone" button, or is there only one "clone" button? If there is only one button, which row should it cone?

Comment: Now I have each row a clone button

Comment: Is that what you want to have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149230/discussion-between-fred-gandt-and-mofiqul-islm).

Answer (score -1):

use append() function of jQuery to do like this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#more"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<label><input type="text" name="hello"/><button class="remove_field">&#10006;</button></label>'); //add input box
        }
    });
   
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        //e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  e.preventDefault(); $(this).closest('label').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
 <button class="add_field_button">Add More Member</button>
 <table id="more">
   <input type="text" name="hello"/>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: you can't just give a technic without showing a practical example

Comment: I am not expert in Jquery and JS can you please give a small demo of the code that how it will look like.

Comment: This person is not using jquery at all, seems like overkill it import that huge library for just one little function

Comment: @Jonathan  One of SO moderator told me not to share answer directly in code. Just reply how to solve it. that's why i did

Comment: @ChrisBarr I'm try to make easy for him, so i don't think it is bad